Why would my ability to infer the 2nd argument be impacted by also inferring the 1st?
I have some types for my router
import {Plugin} from 'vue'

type Route = {
  name: string,
  path: string,
}

type Options = Partial<{
  rejections: Record<string, unknown>
}>

type Router<TRoutes extends Route[], TOptions extends Options = Options> = {
  routes: TRoutes
} & Plugin

function createRouter<
  const TRoutes extends Route[],
  const TOptions extends Options
>(routes: TRoutes, options: TOptions): Router<TRoutes, TOptions>{
  return {
    install: () => {},
    routes
  }
}

const myRouter = createRouter([
  {name: 'home', path: '/'}
], {rejections: { AuthNeeded: 1}})

interface Register {
  router: typeof myRouter
}

I use this Register interface to pull off things like RegisteredRoutes
type RegisteredRoutes = Register extends {router: Router<infer TRoutes>} ? TRoutes : []

as well things from the options, which is where this issue arrives.
type RegisteredRejections = Register extends { router: Router<Route[], infer TOptions> } ? keyof TOptions['rejections'] : never

I expected RegisteredRejections to equal 'AuthNeeded' but instead I get generic string.
What really breaks my brain is the 2 ways I've found to fix it, neither makes any sense to me.
#1 when inferring the options argument, also infer the routes argument
type RegisteredRejections = Register extends { router: Router<infer TRoutes, infer TOptions> } ? keyof TOptions['rejections'] : never

#2 alternatively, uncomment the & Plugin portion of the Router definition
type Router<TRoutes extends Route[], TOptions extends Options = Options> = {
  routes: TRoutes
}

here's a vue SFC playground
UPDATE by Alexander Nenashev
TS Playground
But for some reason the type inferred as never

BTW, this router I'm working on is @kitbag/router. Here's the PR where I "fixed" the issue https://github.com/kitbagjs/router/pull/384/files#diff-95ec5f93a0b15cfb2c6c37871ebe56f29b5608055b475fe1814d21eddff87f08

If you don't get enough engagement here, you might consider trying to make it a pure TS question instead of having a vue dependency. If such an edit with a pure-TS [mre] happens I'll take another look. Good luck!

@jcalz added TS playground, but it infers differently
